# C# Regex, no reconoce el patrón a pesar de ser correcto

Tags: c#, regex, pdf, scraping

Buenas estoy intentando hacer un programa para sacar información de un pdf, y cuando he dado el patrón regex que iba aplicar al texto, este no se comporta igual que las otras opciones que tengo para probar regex.(El texto que utilizo en regex101 es el que hay en la variable ExtractedText)

*(?<=Empresa Española:).+?(?=Empresa Española)*

Notas:
Si solo pongo, "Empresa Española", me reconoce la mención de esas dos palabras todas la veces que aparecen en el texto.

¿Debería probar a generar otro patrón? ¿O hay alguna solución para que pueda utilizar en C# ese tipo de regex?

[image: Probando el patrón en regex101]
[image: vista de depuración]
[image: solo 'Empresa Española']

```
namespace espanya

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            long length = new System.IO.FileInfo("morocco.pdf").Length;
            string ExtractedText = ExtractTextFromPdf();
            Regex namepattern = new Regex("@(?<=Empresa Española:).+?(?=Empresa Española)");
            
            MatchCollection nname = namepattern.Matches(ExtractedText);
          

        }

     public static string ExtractTextFromPdf()
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("morocco.pdf"))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
                }

                return text.ToString();
            } 
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: En el texto de prueba, mira si funciona con mayúsculas las palabras "Empresa Española".

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿y si revisas los índices de las palabras "Empresa española", y copias la cadena que está entre cada uno de esos índices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La razón por la que falla la expresión regular es porque `.` selecciona cualquier caracter excepto el salto de línea.

En **regex101** funciona porque lo estás probando mal. Nota que tienes escrito `\n` literalmente, por lo tanto, regex ve los caracteres **\** y **n** en lugar de un salto de línea.

La solución es simple, activa el flag `s` (single line) y el punto también seleccionará los saltos de línea.

En C# puedes activarlos desde el constructor:

```
new Regex(@"regex", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

También es probable que quieras usar `IgnoreCase` y `Compiled` para que la búsqueda sea más rápida. Puedes combinarlos con el operador `|`, por ejemplo: `RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline`. Más opciones [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options).

Comment: Con que eso era! Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente ^^

Comment: @mTx marca la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado, de ese modo aportas a la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D